# Port Forwarding Issue on ONT

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I have a Huawei ONT device and some devices in the local network that need to be accessed from WAN side (CCTV port:37777 & SAMBA Port 445). So I have added some port mappings. While all of the intended devices are accessible from LAN and WAN, one of them is easily accessible from LAN but not WAN (Port 1364)!
Any Ideas? Are there anything else that I need to share to clarify the issue?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you currently have a service that's listening for connections on port 1364?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue...
On the target device, when gateway is set incorrectly, there will be no problem in local access but WAN access will fail.